# Check whether a string contains a None Type value python

Tags: python, string, nonetype

I am writing to a csv file in Python. But when I try to open and read it I get:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

My question is, how can I check before I write something whether my string contains a None type value.

Thanks

Comment: Inspect the code this None comes from. You most likely have a bug; perhaps you tried to assign the return value of an in-place operation to a variable? Something like `this_will_be_None = some_list.append(whatever)`.

Comment: Possibly just pedantry on my part, possibly you've misunderstood something and it's worth correcting that. Your string doesn't *contain* the value `None`. You have the value `None` *instead of* a string. There is no "my string", you don't have a string, that's the problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is not` (which [is recommended](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) to compare with singletons like `None`):

```
if some_string is not None:
    # write
```